# RegEx unicode name validation (only dash, dot, space, apostrof allowed)

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, unicode

(I searched for this question, but only found good enough solutions that require the use of a unicode plugin. I can't use that.)

I want to validate an input field (first and lastname) with the following criteria:

- No numbers allowed,
- `. - '` (dot, dash, apostrof and **SPACE**) are allowed,
- no other symbols or special characters allowed,
- I want to accept all unicode characters

`[a-zA-Z]` is off the table, because it dies when accented characters are entered.
I started with `^([^0-9]*)$` that is capable of fulfilling all the criteria above, except one: it allows all special characters, not just `.-'` and space.

Is it possible to modify `^([^0-9]*)$`, so that it complies with the special character criteria yet accepts all unicode characters?

Comment: Maybe it is easier to specify the symbols that you don't allow (e.g. `[^$@#%^&*()]+`). I personally don't see any point in validating names. If a user wants to use a fake name and you don't allow symbols, the user can still put zzz or zazaza. So why bother?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`\p{L}`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) (that matches any kind of letter from any language), combinating it with JS [XRegExp library](http://xregexp.com/).

```js
var str1 = "aàp'èéìa skopI(989'j0.ç-' dc sAù_";
var str2 = "aàp'èéìa skopI'j.-' dc sAù";

regex = XRegExp('^[\\p{L} \'.-]+$');

console.log(regex.test(str1));   // this should return false
console.log(regex.test(str2));   // this should return true
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xregexp/2.0.0/xregexp-all-min.js"></script>
```